# loading of external javascript file in angular5

Tags: angular5

Hi I want to add an External javascript file to the Html. I Have Added the Javascript file to index.html but it gives filenotfound error in anglar5 pleasehelp me to solve the issue.

here is the screenshots of file and error.

Here is the Code:

```
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="lightslider.js"></script>
```

> (index):12 GET http://localhost:4200/lightslider.js net::ERR_ABORTED
>   10:52:43.674

Thanks In Advance.